# Assign Postman Raw JSON Data To variable in Code C# after sending request

Tags: c#, .net, postman

I want to assign the raw JSON to a variable in C# after sending the request. This is so that I can check against it for particular value. essentially add validation.

I have no idea where to start this. I do know that after I get the JSON data into a variable though I will have exactly what I need.

Comment: The question is unclear. JSON is text, so `raw JSON` is still text. You can't validate the contents of a string without parsing it first. If post JSON to an ASP.NET Core endpoint or controller action that expects a specific object, ASP.NET Core itself will validate the JSON string while parsing it and return an RFC7807 validation error response

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: figured it out on my own through mapping "auto mapper"